# Visual Studio - Include in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Bom dia, 
estou em um projeto em que uso o Visual Studio para o backend em C# e o VS Code para o front em JS.

Quando crio uma pasta no vs Code, eu sempre preciso ir no Solution Explorer do Visual Studio e dar um include in project. As vezes acabo me esquecendo de fazer isso o que me gera alguns problemas até que eu veja que nao inclui no projeto. Existe uma forma que eu nao precise fazer isso?

Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: se fizer Add > New Folder na solution ela não some

Comment: Sim Ricardo, se criar dentro do Visual Studio, na solution ela não some. A dúvida é como fazer quando eu adiciono lá pelo VS code. Se tem como já dar o "Include" direto.

Comment: Quando você está acessando os arquivos pelo VS Code, está apenas navegando até um diretório na sua máquina, O Visual Studio não tem como identificar que esses arquivos criados e alterados por outro programa fazem parte da Solution... talvez o que você possa fazer é abrir a sln no VS Code ou se acessar o seu programa partindo do diretório raiz, talvez ele identifique a sln lá